# How to setup AzureDevOps proxy for AzureDevOps?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

We have an Azure DevOps organization in Azure Devops Service [ Not On-premise ]

Getting sources is taking 30+ minutes, and i'm setting up a AzureDevOps Proxy to cache against dev.azure.com

I get the below error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUCvP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not any Azure DevOps Azure. Assume you are talking about **Azure DevOps Service**, the cloud version of Azure DevOps Server.

According to your screenshot. Looks like you were trying to add your Azure DevOps Service to  your server list.

You are using the wrong url and no need to specify port and path in this case.

The url should be like below:

```
https://dev.azure.com/[organization-name]
```